# Show Rails Carrierwave URL without exposing entire path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm making a webapp with paid downloads, and I followed Carrierwave's guide for [protecting uploads](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-secure-upload).  Everything is working as expecting save one thing.  Here's my current setup:

---

**Product File Uploader**

```
...
def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/downloads/#{model.product_id}/#{model.id}"
end
...
```

**Routes**

```
  get "/downloads/:product_id/:product_file_id/:filename", :controller => "products", action: "download", conditions: {method: :get}
```

**ProductsController**

```
def download
  product_file = ProductFile.find(params[:product_file_id])
  name = File.basename(product_file.file.file.file)
  send_file "#{Rails.root}/downloads/#{product_file.product.id}/#{product_file.id}/#{name}", :x_sendfile => true
end
```

---

The problem is with the download path.  Because I specified `#{Rails.root}` in the File Uploader, the file saves in a folder external from the public folder called `downloads`.  This has an unintended side effect, however.   When I retrieve the URL from my model, I get the entire absolute path, not the path relative to the Rails Root.

So for instance, `ProductFile.first.file.url` returns `"/home/doomy/Documents/resamplr/downloads/3/1/aaaa.zip"`, when it should instead just return `/downloads/3/1/aaa.zip`.

This behaviour seems to be attached to what is specified in the `ProductFileUploader`.

For instance, if I change the `store_dir` to `"/downloads/#{model.product_id}/#{model.id}"`, I get an access error as it is trying to upload to the root of my PC.  `"downloads/#{model.product_id}/#{model.id}"` simply uploads to a new folder in the `public` directory called downloads, which is not what I want to do.

Any advice on how to proceed?  Thanks.

---

Edit:

I have found that setting the `config.root` in a Carrierwave config file to the `Rails.root` allows for this behavior.  If I do this, in my `ProductFileUploader` I can specify the `store_dir` as `"downloads/#{model.product_id}/#{model.id}`.

However, this means public files are saved with a "/public/..." link.  Rails automatically discards the public foldername and uses subdirectory names in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to solve this!

In each uploader, there is a special method called `root` that we can use to set the unseen filepath.  First, I made a special uploader base class called PublicUploader.

```
class PublicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def root
    "${Rails.root}/public"
  end
end
```

Then, I set the global CarrierWave root to the Rails.root.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  # These permissions will make dir and files available only to the user running
  # the servers
  config.permissions = 0600
  config.directory_permissions = 0700
  config.storage = :file

  # This avoids uploaded files from saving to public/ and so
  # they will not be available for public (non-authenticated) downloading
  config.root = Rails.root
end
```

---

This means in my private file uploader I can simply write

```
def store_dir
  "downloads/#{model.product_id}/#{model.id}"
end
```

and it will save in `"#{Rails.root}/downloads/..."` as opposed to `"#{Rails.root}/public/downloads/..."`.  This means I can use a controller to limit access.

However, in my public uploader, I simply had...

```
def store_dir
  "public/downloads/#{model.product_id}/#{model.id}"
end
```

...because I wanted to save in my `"#{Rails.root}/public"` folder.  However, this meant that rails would show a url like the following

`/public/downloads/myfile.jpg`

This poses a problem, as Rails omits the `public` from the path.  So the above would 404.  However when the uploader inherits from the special class where I define the `root`, then I can simply say

```
def store_dir
  "downloads/#{model.product_id}/#{model.id}"
end
```

It will upload and show the image correctly!  Hope this can help someone.