# Using Carrierwave and Capistrano with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, carrierwave, production

I'm having trouble getting carrierwave and capistrano to play nice with each other.

To start, I'm using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337412/show-rails-carrierwave-url-without-exposing-entire-path) to use both a public directory, and a private controller-handled directory for downloads.  Tl;dr, carrierwave's root is actually `Rails.root`, and not `public`.  However, I got around this for urls (since Rails does not use `public` literally in the url) by defining a base class that sets the public root, for all non-private files.

Anyways, I finally started to try and push code to production.  All went well!  My uploads showed just fine.  However, when I pushed another deploy, I lost all of my images in the public directory.

This is a well documented case for capistrano - it only involves setting `:linked_dirs`.  In my case, I used the following line.

```
set :linked_dirs,  %w{public/assets public/uploads downloads}
```

Where `public/assets` were my general css/js files, `public/uploads` were my multimedia files, and `downloads` were my protected files.

Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem.  For whatever reason, all images are getting a `404` despite showing to be listed in the correct path.

Weirder still, the protected `downloads` folder works just fine!  Perhaps this has something to do with setting the root in Carrierwave?  At this point I'm tempted to just pick up paperclip for my public files, and carrierwave for private ones.

I've been at this for a good 7 hours and I still can't figure out what to do.

my [deploy.rb](https://ghostbin.com/paste/yb4hn) file

my problematic [image uploader](https://ghostbin.com/paste/ttxph) file

my working [product file uploader](https://ghostbin.com/paste/pho22) file

my [nginx.conf](https://ghostbin.com/paste/8rzbn) file

Comment: Same as you have been trying to complete my capistrano deploy I am 99% done but still few small issues, I have not specified root in my case I just have `def store;"system/ckeditor/pictures/#{model.id}";end;`, so I assume in your case you can try commenting `def root`.

Comment: Have you set up carrierwave to use Rails.root by default instead of the public dir?  I unfortunately tried this and it did not work.

Comment: I have added my [files here](https://gist.github.com/sahil290791/4ec9ad72dd0c58ce99b39b93710f70e6), I noticed a change in your's and mine `nginx.conf` file could be because you are using puma and I use `phusion passenger`, you have `location ^~ /assets/ {`, where as I have `location ^~ /system/ {` and then root defined again inside the file `root /home/deploy/apps/x/current/public;`. I was able to complete my capistrano deployment with the final changes in `nginx.conf` as till sometime back I was getting 404 not found for the images which were present in `public/system`.

Comment: if this is a new project then I would recommend to go with aws s3 storage and change the `storage` option in `carrierwave` to `storage :fog`, as we have been using combination of s3 and storing files on locally on server. Setting the storage option to `file`, was a big  mistake which let to s3 mounting which would get unmounted frequently which is a pain (can be fixed by scripts). Directly uploading the file to s3 gives you an **advantage** to use `expiring download URLs` plus you do not have to worry about syncing your local folder, which I guess would help you in case of `private downloads`.

Comment: Have you verified that the files are indeed getting written to /public/uploads? If so, what are the permissions on those files?

Comment: The permissions being set in your other Stack Overflow post to make the files private may be preventing nginx from reading them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [other question & answer you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337618/237098), you've set restrictive permissions on the CarrierWave upload directory and files:

```
# Broken permissions
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0600
  config.directory_permissions = 0700
  config.storage = :file
end
```

`0600` and `0700` permissions only grant access to the user that owns the file or directory. This is because both the third & fourth bits, "group" and "everyone", are set to 0.

nginx, Puma, and Capistrano probably aren't all running under the same user, which means these user-only permissions block nginx from reading the files (causing 403 errors after upload) and block Capistrano from linking the `public/uploads` directory (causing 404 errors after new deploys).

Instead, use more open permissions, such as what's listed on the [CarrierWave README](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#configuring-carrierwave):

```
# Fixed permissions
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0666
  config.directory_permissions = 0777
  config.storage = :file
end
```